# How to add AngularJs directive dynamically from controller?

Tags: angularjs

I want to add an AngularJs directive from the controller.

controller code:

```
    $scope.getLink = function(fileInfo, index)
                {
                    if(fileInfo !== null)
                    {
                    if(fileInfo.fileType.indexOf("image") !== -1)
                    {
                        return $sce.trustAsHtml('<span ng-click="getImage('+ index +', "'
                            + fileInfo.filePath +'")">view</span>');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return $sce.trustAsHtml('<a target="_blank" href="/phoenix/subscriber/getfile' 
                        + fileInfo.filePath+'">download</a>');
                    }
                    }
                };
$scope.getImage = function()
            {
                alert("Done");
            };
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-show="post.fileInfo !== null">
 <div ng-bind-html="getLink(post.fileInfo,$index)"></div>
                    </div>
```

This codes work fine but the problem is that the added the ng-click does not work.

Comment: where is ng-click?

Comment: If it was me, I would put the variability out in the html. That is ng-if image, show image html, ng-if not image,  show link.

Comment: Also that would fix your click issue. I suppose it is not working at the moment because the html sent from controller is not compiled. So the ng-click does not carry any meaning (as it is not treated as a directive,  being linked etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to manage the view this way when angular has directives built in like `ng-if` or `ng-show` to manage this in the view

You don't need that function at all

```
<div ng-show="post.fileInfo !== null">
  <div>
    <span ng-if="post.fileInfo.fileType.indexOf('image') !== -1"
          ng-click="getImage($index,post.fileInfo.filePath)">view</span>
    <a ng-if="post.fileInfo.fileType.indexOf('image') === -1" 
       target="_blank" 
       ng-href="/phoenix/subscriber/getfile/{{post.fileInfo.filePath}}">download</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

The reason your approach was not working is when inserting directives yourself you need to use `$compile`

A simple directive could be used here also